# Why does IE break my image colours?

Tags: firefox, colors, internet-explorer-7

I have a site that I have built, with a colour scheme based around the companies graphic. This has a gradient from left to right, fading to white. I use the image at the top of the pages.

To provide the same gradient down the page, I took a pixel or two wide cut from the bottom of this image, which I them repeat down my page. This works perfectly well, giving me the right gradient across my screen.

In firefox, there is no break between the bottom of my header image and the top of my repeated background gradient - which is as expected. The colours match, so they should appear continuous. However, in IE7, the top image appears very slightly lighter than the rest of the background. I initially thought that this was because I think IE does not always render style colours correctly, but then I realised that it is not a style, it is an image. I cannot understand why these two images are being rendered differently.

Unfortunately, because of who my client is, I cannot include pictures, and I accept that this will make it harder for anyone to answer, but if there are any suggestions, I would love to know why this is happening.

Thank you.

Comment: We can't work blind. Got an example?

Comment: I realise it is difficult without the images, which is why I was after possibilities. fortunately @jos found an a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving them in a different format. I think this has to do wkth color calibration performed in certain computers (can be set up in Windows fo example, but as I am writing this on the go from my mobile I cant/wont do more research). I think JPEG des not care about this setting and PNG do, or the other way around. Someone else can probably describe it way better..

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem. The top image was saved as a jpg, and the background as png. It is still frustrating that this was only an issue on ie, which was behaving differently to ff. Ah well. Many thanks.